# typecasting doesnt work when using mod operation from long to int

Tags: java, long-integer

I have to reverse a given number and store it in linked list, in this case the number was 10000000000 so I declared it as long and the expected output is 00000000001 with each digit in each node of a linked list.

But for some reason, the output I get is 80000000001

this is the code I tried

```
        add = new ListNode((int)v3%10); 
        temp3 = add;
        v3 = v3/10;
        while (v3 != 0)
        {

            //System.out.println("value of v3 "+v3);
               temp3.next = new ListNode((int)v3%10);
                temp3 = temp3.next;
                v3 = v3/10;
        }
```

the result should be [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]

Comment: Please **edit** your post to be a reproducible example (e.g. we can run the code **and** get the reported output). **Guessing** you've input the number in octal (but that's a **guess**).

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with typecasting I can not see any typecasting exception. it's logic error.
Here the code you can look at it I replaced your ListNode with Java's built in LinkedList

```
    LinkedList<Integer> linkedList = new LinkedList<>();
    long  v3 = 10000_0000_00L;
    long longmodulo= v3 % 10;
    linkedList.add((int) longmodulo);

    v3 = v3/10;

    while (v3 != 0){
        long longmodulo2= v3 % 10;
        linkedList.add((int) longmodulo2);

        v3 = v3/10;
        System.out.println("value of v3 "+v3);
    }
    linkedList.forEach(System.out::println);
```